# Install any Linux flavor on Macbook Pro early 2011

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, fedora, macbook-pro

I am trying to install Linux on my MacBook Pro. I would prefer Fedora but XUbuntu or Ubuntu is fine also.  The firmware does not support the last Linux versions.  The only OS I could install was Ubuntu 10.10 but it gave me several problems, like no internet connection and several issues that you can find in this [**thread**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1730355&page=2) on the Ubuntu forums.

I need Linux for several reasons in my study and I don't want to use a virtual machine because I don't have enough memory.  Is there anybody that had my same problem and solved it or can redirect me to a good guide to avoid/correct this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The booting issue is well known - the SATA chipset that the 8.2 uses is (was?) not well supported by Linux. [The fix](http://marpoz.blogspot.com/2012/01/ubuntu-on-macbook-pro-82.html) for this comes down to:

1. Find a USB flash drive and a blank disk.
2. Download the AMD64 Mac ISO, and burn it onto the CD.
3. Write the ISO onto the thumbdrive using `dd`.
4. Place the USB drive and the CD in, and reboot onto the CD.

The 8.2 uses a Broadcom 4331 card, you **have** to go with the open source driver, as Broadcom's binary driver doesn't support the 4331. The patch was accepted in kernel version 3.2, which Ubuntu 12.04 has.

The firmware, however, is not redistributable with the default install - as such, find an ethernet cable and install the `firmware-b43-installer` package.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently, today, installed Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop on my early 2011 Macbook Pro and it runs AWESOME! i7-2635QM, 512gb SSD, 16gb RAM. Everything works. Ubuntu 20.04 is very mature for installing on this model, and this is from recent personal experience.

Download the ISO, burn it onto USB (I'm a hardcore command line warrior so I was able to do all this in a terminal window with diskutil and dd) and reboot your MacBook while holding down the Option key. The first it boots you'll see 2 EFI drives. Select the first one, and your Ubuntu install will start.

I chose to go the Ubuntu Linux ONLY route and completely scrapped the unsupported version of OSX (High Sierra IIRC) and now I have a kickass little LinuxBook. When the Ubuntu 20.04 installation got to the part where it wants to know which disk, I chose ERASE EVERYTHING and gave the whole drive to Ubuntu Linux.

Might be the best thing I've ever done on this laptop. Plus now IO have a nice little toy to trick out over the next week or so plus I can alleviate some disk and memory on my desktop workhorse and get rid of a couple Virtual Box Linux VM's and replace/add the functionality to this native Linux environment.

I performed this on 2021.09.26 so it's fresh in my mind now if you decide to do the same.

Thanks,
Ron